# webp for CSS background images

Tags: css, webp

Trying to figure out how to server webp images from a style sheet for tag elements WITHOUT a selector. For example, **header**.

For example:

```
.no-webp header {
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.73), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 26.05%), url('../img/my-image.jpg');
```

}
.webp .header {
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.73), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 26.05%), url('../img/my-image.webp');
}

The above code does not display either the jpg or webp.

Comment: Have you got the url of the images right? I ask because your css works fine for me with my own image (a jpg)- that is, the top part is darkened. Could you put up a working snippet which shows the problem.

Comment: I figured it out - see below.

Answer (score -1):

I corrected this by using modernizr.custom.js with support for .webp and .no-webp. The page is now serving webp images.